# Installation of fontawesome in MiKTeX

Tags: fonts, packages, fontawesome

I'm trying to install fontawesome in MiKTeX 2.9 (Windows). Here's what I've done:

Downloaded the .zip from [CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fontawesome), unzipped and copied that into the directory c:\localtexfiles\tex\latex\fontawesome, run Refresh FNDB and Update Formats in MiKTeX Options. The directory c:\localtexfiles is declared a root directory in MiKTeX.

A minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\begin{document}
\faTwitter
\end{document}
```

yields the following [log](http://pastebin.com/bvg83Ddb). Any ideas on what's wrong?

Comment: Why didn't you do it through MiKTeX Package Manager? That said, you didn't have to refresh the formats, but write a personal `updmap.cfg` mentioning  fontawesome, then run `updmap` from the command line. With MPM, only the last step has to be done.

Comment: Why don't you use the package manager of miktex?

Comment: @Bernard, @Ulrike Fischer: Searching for 'fontawesome' in the package manager didn't yield any results, so I thought I had to manually install it. How could it have been done via the package manager? I did try adding 'Map fontawesome.map' to 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\config\updmap.cfg' and then running `updmap` in command line. This is the log: http://pastebin.com/BbAFYbcQ

Comment: You should go to the menu `Repository> Synchronise` to update the database of available packages, and maybe launch MiKTeX Update.

Comment: @Bernard: Thanks, wasn't aware of that option. Now it compiles running `latex` but the font is not viewable / not loadable in YAP (it shows the number 7 in my minimal example). If I try to run `dvipdfm`, it doesn't output a .pdf. This is the log: http://pastebin.com/J1FwgTvw How do I end up with a viewable .pdf?

Comment: Did  you run `updmap --verbose` from the command line (as administrator)?

Comment: @Bernard: Apparently not as administrator because it seems to be running now. Thanks a lot for the help - much appreciated.

Comment: As administrator is not strictly necessary, but another user won't have access to the font.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is solved by comments ...